# E: Package 'libmysqlclient18' has no installation candidate

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I am installing mysql on Ubuntu 16.04 following https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install

> install the shared client libraries:
>
> ```
>  shell> sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18
> ```

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libmysqlclient18 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libmysqlclient18' has no installation candidate
```

How shall I solve the error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The package `libmysqlclient18` is in 12.04 and 14.04 only. Not 16.04.

The package `libmysqlclient20` is in 16.04 and newer (as of JUN 2018)

Please let the mysql team know that their documentation needs to be updated.

Comment: I would even recommend to use `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient
`  leaving the version to be determined at the install time.

Comment: Hmmm. There is no `libmysqlclient` metapackage (or ordinary package)  in the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:        19.04
Codename:       disco

sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community libmysqlclient20

this way works better 
----->         sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient20